# Compass to annotation with Titanium

Tags: annotations, location, titanium, compass-geolocation, heading

I'am trying to build a compass that heading to a annotation with Titanium on a map. It's already succeeded me to build a normal compass with the compass function in Titanium.

I am unable to make the compass point the right direction from the location. Has anyone a script or example what works?

```
    if (Titanium.Geolocation.hasCompass){

    var transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();

    // Settings
    Titanium.Geolocation.showCalibration = true;
    Titanium.Geolocation.headingFilter = 0;

    Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentHeading(function(e){

        if (e.error){
            Titanium.API.info("error: " + e.error);
            return;
        }

        var animationNorth = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
            transform   : transform.rotate(e.heading.trueHeading),
            duration    : 50
        });

        // Rotate image to north
        compassNorth.animate(animationNorth);

        headingLabel.setText('geo - current heading: ' + e.heading.trueHeading);
    });

    Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('heading', function(e){

        if (e.error){
            Titanium.API.info("error: " + e.error);
            return;
        }

        var animationNorth = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
            transform   : transform.rotate(e.heading.trueHeading),
            duration    : 50
        });

        // Rotate image to north
        compassNorth.animate(animationNorth);

        headingLabel.setText('geo - current heading: ' + e.heading.trueHeading);
    });

} else {
    headingLabel.setText("No Compass on device");
}
```

Comment: so what have you already tried to solve your problem? what's the exact issue?

Comment: Thanks for you're fast comment. I had already the calculations for a heading between 2 point [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). But I need to now witch direct my phone pointing. I now use the compass function, but this only point to the north. I added my compass code to my post

Comment: If you know where you are, and where the point you want to go is, and you know where North is, can't you calculate the number of degrees from North the other point is?